# Any way to downgrade Ubuntu One recent updates?

Tags: ubuntu-one, downgrade

Im running the Ubuntu One nightlies PPA on my 10.10 Meerkat installation. It works great on my home desktop and on my laptop, but at work I did an update the other day that updated the Ubuntu One packages and now U1 no longer works on my work computer. Any way to downgrade, roll back, or fix this?

Here are the files that my home system is trying to update (if it helps any)...

[image]

Im not updating these since U1 works fine at home!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [ppa-purge](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ppa-purge) [image: Install ppa-purge].

Answer (score 0):

Remove the PPA, update repos, remove Ubuntu One, install Ubuntu One.